# Query Profiler for Couchbase

Tags: database, performance, nosql, profiler, couchbase

I have recently started experimenting with Couchbase 2.0. What would be a good way to measure time taken by operations like inserts, aggregation etc. in couchbase? Is there a profiler available?

One basic way would be to measure the time taken to excecute the rest api commands but that would include network latency. What I'm looking for is the time taken by the processor to run the commands.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can see high-level ops/sec, broken down into various operations
(reads, writes, etc.) from the UI console when monitoring a data bucket. The
'cbstats' tool has a 'timings' histogram option which will report the times
for operations, and breaks it down into important parts of the operation
such as how long it took to read items off of disk if necessary, or how long
to complete a delete operation, etc.
The documentation for this command ca be found [here](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-cmdline-cbstats.html)